# How to create a part of word in list item of HTML

Tags: html, listitem

I have a question about HTML. I have a list like this: Where it says A is ordered list, next is unordered list.

A.Flower, grows on grass

- -tulip

  - rose

I do now how to create that Flower will be in blue color and the another part of text wil be red (grows on grass). Is it possible to create something like this. I know you can only create styles but separately for unordered and ordered list but for parts of words in list item...

Comment: Basic CSS should be able to handle this, I think.  Any tutorial should be able to lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Give id to the part you want to change and using the id selector in css you can perform the color change.